# What is choppy throttle response and bad fuel mapping and can it be fixed?

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-injection, triumph, tt600, ecu-mapping

I'm looking to purchase a motorcycle and according to it's wikipedia article it has two major flaws:

> Being the company's first fuel-injected 600cc sportbike, the initial
>   2000 model had choppy throttle response and bad fuel mapping, leading
>   to harsh on/off throttle transitions.

What does this mean? Is it possible to fix it?

[Triumph TT600 Wiki Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triumph_TT600)

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell, the later models (2002 / 2003) had a new fuel map and were a lot smoother.  It ought to be possible to remap the ECU on the bike or possibly replace it with one from a later model.

If you find a prospective bike to purchase ride it and see how it feels.  It may be that the fuel map on the bike has already been adjusted, if not, budget for a remap.

Comment: One would think that the guys who designed and built the bike had ridden it at least once before signing off on it.

Comment: I'm guessing it should feel fine but if it's not working what would it feel like? Also, any estimate on what a remap would cost?

Answer (score 1):

The on/off throttle transitions can be resolved by a mixture of remapping ECUs (in the case of a fuel injected bike) or re-jetting the carburetors as well as fitting a "Throttle Tamer Tube" to your accelerator handle.  Basically its a slightly different shaped cam on the Throttle handle that slows down/speeds up the transition so between on and off throttle so that the bike behaves more as you expect/want it to.

An example of a [throttle tamer can be seen here](http://www.mandp.co.uk/index.php/default/40-4f-136-throttle-tamer-tube.html)

[image: Throttle Tamer tube]

If you look at the left side you will see the tube is shaved slightly to slow the response down a bit (i.e. slow the butterfly in the throttle body opening so fast), others can be found that speed up the throttle opening.

Answer (score 1):

**This problem can be resolved by using [TuneECU](http://www.tuneecu.com/)**

**[TuneECU](http://www.tuneecu.com/)** is a free tool supported by a community.  I am unsure if it's open source.

This tool can access your ECU and change individual settings within the map based upon throttle position and RPM.

You will want to download map number **10166** and upload that map into your ECU via the TuneECU application.

This will take away that choppy feeling coming off idle.

**Other Known Issue**

Another very common issue with your model year is the IACV (Idle Air Control Valve) vacuum lines.  They crack and fall off the IAC valve and creat vacuum leaks that result in poor idle and stalling.

Validate all of your vacuum lines are in good shape and attached properly.

This will remediate your issues.